# How to modify the Python 'default' dictionary so that it always returns a default value

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.4

I'm using all of them to print the names of assigned IANA values in a packet. So all of the dictionaries have the same default value "RESERVED".

I don't want to use `d.get(key,default)` but access dictionaries by `d[key]` so that if the key is not in d, it returns the default (that is same for all dictionaries).

I do not necessarily need to use dictionaries, but they were the intuitive choice...
Also, a dictionary where I could do this

```
d = {
   1..16 = "RESERVED",
   17 : "Foo",
   18 : "Bar,
   19..255: "INVALID"
  }
```

Would be the preferred solution

Tuples could be another alternative, but then I'm prone to offset errors assigning the values... (and my code would not be "human readable")

Oh yeah, Python 2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, use [Mario's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605750/how-to-modify-the-python-default-dictionary-so-that-it-always-returns-a-default/1605802#1605802).

If you can't, you just have to subclass a dictionary-like object. Now, you can do that by inheriting directly from "dict", it will be fast and efficient. For old Python versions, with which you can't inherit from "dict", there is "UserDict", a pure Python dictionary implementation.

With it, you would do it this way :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding= UTF-8 -*-

import UserDict

class DefaultDict(UserDict.UserDict) :

    default_value = 'RESERVED'

    def __getitem__(self, key) :
        return self.data.get(key, DefaultDict.default_value)


d = DefaultDict()
d["yes"] = True;
print d["yes"]
print d["no"]
```

Keep in mind that "UserDict" is slower than "dict".

Comment: I have to go with this approach (looks like 2.4 can include dict so I am not completely lost)... However now I started wondering whether it would be possible create a dictionary-like class that allowed the 'range' assignments.

Comment: What do you mean by range assignment ?

Comment: That should be `self.default_value`, so it functions correctly with subclassing.

Comment: There are a 10 000 things you can improve this snippet. This is just an illustration. A bullet proof code would be  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/523034/

Answer (score 9):

If you can migrate to Python 2.5, there is the *defaultdict* class, as shown [here](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). You can pass it an initializer that returns what you want. Otherwise, you'll have to roll your own implementation of it, I fear.

Comment: If upgrade was an option, I would go for 3.0 altogether, sadly I think I'm stuck with 2.4 so I can run this on EL5 w/o installing a new python...

Comment: And a very clean one. Quite interesting to understand the defaultdict implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following class (tested in Python 2.7)
Just change zero to any default value you like.

```
class cDefaultDict(dict):
    # dictionary that returns zero for missing keys
    # keys with zero values are not stored

    def __missing__(self,key):
        return 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if value==0:
            if key in self:  # returns zero anyway, so no need to store it
                del self[key]
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```